# State Pattern for traffic lights

Tags: c#, design-patterns, state

I tried to implement a traffic light system using state pattern, please comment on the OOP/design pattern use.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace DesignPatternsQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// implement a traffic light system
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class StatePatternTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void StateTrafficLightTest()
        {
            TrafficLight light = new TrafficLight(new RedState());
            light.ChangeLight();
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(light.State,typeof(GreenState));
            light.ChangeLight();
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(light.State, typeof(YellowState));
            light.ChangeLight();
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(light.State, typeof(RedState));
            light.ChangeLight();
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(light.State, typeof(GreenState));
        }
    }

    public class TrafficLight
    {
        private State _state;

        public TrafficLight(State state)
        {
            _state = state;
        }
        // Gets or sets the state

        public State State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                _state = value;
                Console.WriteLine("State: " +
                  _state.GetType().Name);
            }
        }
        //this is the trickS
        public void ChangeLight()
        {
            _state.SetState(this);
        }
    }

    public abstract class State
    {
        public abstract void SetState(TrafficLight light);
    }

    public class RedState: State
    {
        public override void SetState(TrafficLight light)
        {
            light.State = new GreenState();
        }
    }

    public class YellowState : State
    {
        public override void SetState(TrafficLight light)
        {
            light.State = new RedState();
        }
    }

    public class GreenState : State
    {
        public override void SetState(TrafficLight light)
        {
            light.State = new YellowState();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `State` class is overkill here when simple `enum` or even declared int constants could be used.  I would also consider 2 other states: None (with a value of 0) for when all lights are off or malfunctioning, and BlinkingRed.  Where I live there is also blinking yellow left turn arrows to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Design

This sort of design isn't necessarily a bad thing, but in this example it's making things a lot more complicated, without providing any benefits:

- `ChangeLight` suggests that `null` is not a valid state, but your `TrafficLight` class does not prevent its state from being initialized or set to `null`.
- It's possible to create classes that inherit from `State` or one of your other state classes. This essentially means that there are an infinite number of possible states (`PurpleState`, `RandomState`, `SchrodingerCatState`, ...). That makes it unclear how exactly your traffic light is meant to be used.
- Those state classes don't contain any actual state - it's only their type (and functionality) that matters. In that case, you might as well create static instances that can be reused. And because they all contain essentially the same logic (just different values), you don't really need separate classes either.
- Methods like `AllowTraffic` and `StopTraffic(TimeSpan delay)` are probably more useful than a `ChangeLight` method that doesn't say anything about what the next state will be. But supporting such methods with logic inside those state classes alone is cumbersome.

Using a simple `enum` instead makes things a lot easier: there's no `null` to worry about and it's immediately clear what all the possible states are. The light-changing logic is fairly simple, so that can easily be kept in `TrafficLight` itself.

#### Further considerations

Different countries use different light patterns, and traffic lights may have different modes (such as daylight versus night, or an error state). In other words: red is not always followed by green - in some countries there's an orange-red state in-between, in some modes a light is flashing red continually, and so on.

With such requirements, the current light doesn't tell us everything about the traffic light's internal state. It would be more useful to treat each *pattern* as a different state. But even then I wouldn't create separate state classes with their own logic: a single data-driven class and some state-tracking logic inside `TrafficLight` itself should be sufficient.

#### Other notes

- That `Console.WriteLine` is obviously some left-over test code, but be careful not to leave it lingering around. There's no reason why this code should depend on the presence of a console. If you're using Visual Studio, you may want to use tracepoints instead (breakpoints with a logging action). They're more flexible and don't clutter the code.
- Comments like `// Gets or sets the state` are of no use: they're just stating the obvious, and they can only cause confusion when they become out-of-date.
- `State` is a very generic name - `TrafficLightState` or `TrafficLightColor` may be more appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought the whole point of state pattern is thr abstract class of state but i will try to implement with an enum as well. Thanks.

Comment: The way I see it is that the state pattern is more about providing different behavior for different states. For example, a traffic light control system could have different modes: normal, where each lane is given the same amount of time, rush-hour, where certain lanes are prioritized, or maintenance mode, where lights are disabled or manually controlled. Each mode has its own logic and maybe mode-specific state. That seems like a good use-case for this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

[Pieter's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/203483/13424) already covers most of the important things, I just want to add a small bit (that's why it's a community wiki instead of a comment) about the logic behind a state machine for a complex system.

Imagine to describe the health *state* of someone: you don't list all the symptoms or the visible outcomes, you just say "flu" (for example). This is a simplification but I hope it helps to understand the point: instead of `TrafficLightColor` the state should describe what it is, not the visible outcome (light is red).

For example (better names are highly recommended): `AboutToStopTraffic`, `StopTraffic`,  `AboutToAllowTraffic` and `AllowTraffic` (if these are the **states** your traffic light system can manage).

Outcomes (color combination and/or other things like traffic cameras' state) are **derived by the state but they're not the state** (even if sometimes they may coincide).

The main advantage is the the *derived outcomes* can be configured separately and independently from the main *immutable* logic. If, for example, in one country there is not a separate light configuration between *stop* and *go* then your logic does not need to be updated in a per-country base.

Answer (score 3):

First, I see no reason to make the setter of `TrafficLight.State` public, as there's no reason the client should be able to change it directly.

Second, your solution looks a bit too complicated to me. As long as you're talking about traffic lights where the number of possible states is finite and should never change, I wouldn't make the`State` property an object, but rather an `enum`. The way you defined it allows the client to call `light.State.SetState(anotherInstanceOfLight)`, which can result in an undesired state (that is, the state of the system, not of a specific traffic light)

Comment: OP's solution is too complicate, IMHO, because he didn't pick the right names and he didn't set clear responsibilities. Outside very simple cases (which this might be or not) a state machine for traffic lights is a good use-case (think about time, calls for pedestrians, traffic conditions and so on...)

Answer (score 1):

Like others stated, using the *state pattern* for this problem is overkill. But when you decide to use it, make the following considerations.

Events `ChangeLight` received by the state machine `TrafficLight` should be forwarded to the state. Your implementation stipulates the state machine decides what the state must do. You have actually implemented a *visitor pattern*, rather than a *state pattern*.

> ```
> public void ChangeLight()
> {
>     _state.SetState(this);  // <- this is a visitor pattern
> }
> ```

```
 public void ChangeLight()
 {
     _state.ChangeLight(this);  // <- let the state handle the event
 }

 public class RedState: State
 {
     public override void ChangeLight(TrafficLight light)
     {
         // Each state decides itself what to do, rather than the traffic light
         // telling them what to do; it just happens to be so that whatever the 
         // traffic light wants the state to do (in your implementation) is what
         // each of these states want to do.
         light.State = new GreenState();
     }
 }
```